# SUMIFS that compares ranges with calculation

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I have two columns, I want to sum the positive values in Colunm A, but only of the ones that are higher in Column A than in negative ColumnB  (ColumnB*-1)
i.e. Column A (1,2,3,-4) 
Column B (0.5, -1.5, -4, 5)

The result would be 1 (1>-0.5) + 2 (2>1.5) = 3, 3 would not be included since 3 is not > (-4) *-1

I hope this is something possible, without creating an additional column that is Column B * -1

Also.. I am inserting this formula via Excel VBA, I can use it in a formula, but I am not sure I could use if it needs to be inserted as an Array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), and I dont think it works by just using {}, when you insert it via Excel VBA.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A4>-(B1:B4),A1:A4,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I perfer to avoid array formula where ever possible, mainly because other users are confused by them.  So I would use a formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4,N(-(B1:B4)<A1:A4))
```